# Duplicate controller names in the route url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

In my project I have to duplicate the `Controllers` in the url to make it work.

for instance,

What I want:

```
http://localhost:53547/Projects/Dashboard/1
```

However, this throws a `404`

What I need to type to make it work:

```
http://localhost:53547/Projects/Projects/Dashboard/1
```

Why is this happening?

This is the `RouteConfig` class that I have:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

And, these are the properties of my project:

[image]

I tried deleting my `bin` folder just in case I had an old build messing everything up. But, nothing.

What else could it be?

Thank you

**EDIT**

If I just type: `http://localhost:53547/Projects`

It will take me to the `Index` view in the `Home` Controller.

Comment: Do you have a Route attribute set on your class? And does this problem persist to other controllers in that class or elsewhere?

Comment: Yes @ThomasBouman, the problem persists with all the actions in the controller. What I pasted is all thatl I have in the class :/

Comment: I meant the class for your controller.

Comment: No, I don't have any attributes there.

Comment: I added an edit to the post. Why do you think is taking the default view as that URL? @ThomasBouman

Comment: Where is your ProjectsController.cs class located? Is it in ..\Controllers\ or in ..\Areas\Projects\Controllers\ ? If it resides inside an Area, you need to provide the name of the Area in the URL (as in the second URL that works).

Comment: It is in Controllers

Comment: And you also don't call `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();` or have any classes inheriting from `AreaRegistration` in your project? (I am still assuming that there is an Area called 'Projects' somewhere that messes up your route).

Comment: I am calling it because it was generated by the project. But, I am not using any areas. Does the Registering of the routes occur every time that I make a request? That's what is happening. A link that is used in every view has a value of href="/Projects", and when I clicked on it, it suddenly changes to href="/Projects/Projects"

Comment: Normally the routing code is put into the Global.asax and runs once on application startup.

Comment: It's been called more than one time. The problem is definitely there then

Comment: The RouteConfig seems fine. Would you post your project structure? "Views & Controllers"